# How do I create a checker board pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write a code that can generate an checker board pattern. The final image size should be `100 x 100`, the checker board size `5 x 5`, such that each box has dimensions `h/5` and `w/5`. The code I have is wrong:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

h = 500
w = 500
img = Image.new("RGB", (h,w), (255, 0, 0))   # create a new 15x15 image
pixels = img.load()                          # create the pixel map
print("1")

for i in range (h):
    for j in range(w):
        if ((i + j)%2) != 0:
            im = Image.new('RGB', (h//5, w//5), 'black')
        else:
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img, "RGBA")
            draw.rectangle(((h//5, w//5), (i+.5, j+.5)), fill="blue")
    
print ("done")
img.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's already been answered, here's a way to loop over it differently

```
from PIL import Image

h = 500
w = 500

# You can also easily set the number of squares per row
number_of_square_across = 10

# You can also easily set the colors
color_one = (0, 0, 0)
color_two = (0, 0, 255)

length_of_square = h/number_of_square_across
length_of_two_squares = h/number_of_square_across*2

img = Image.new("RGB", (h, w), (255, 0, 0))  # create a new 15x15 image
pixels = img.load()  # create the pixel map

for i in range(h):
    # for every 100 pixels out of the total 500 
    # if its the first 50 pixels
    if (i % length_of_two_squares) >= length_of_square:
        for j in range(w):
            if (j % length_of_two_squares) < length_of_square:
                pixels[i,j] = color_one
            else:
                pixels[i,j] = color_two

    # else its the second 50 pixels         
    else:
        for j in range(w):
            if (j % length_of_two_squares) >= length_of_square:
                pixels[i,j] = color_one
            else:
                pixels[i,j] = color_two

print("done")
img.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who reads this in the future and is looking for a general solution to make a checker board see here:

```py
M, N = 10, 10
arr = [[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(M)] # an M by N  array
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        if (i&1)^(j&1): # if (i is odd and j is even) or (j is odd and i is even)
            arr[i][j] = 1 # change the pixel from white to black
```

---

Solution tailored specifically to the OP's inquiry see here:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


h = 500
w = 500
img = Image.new("RGB", (h,w), (255, 0, 0)) # create a new 15x15 image
pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map
print ("1")


for i in range (h):
    for j in range(w):
        if (i&1)^(j&1):
            pixels[i,j] = (0, 0, 0)
        else:
            pixels[i,j] = (0, 0, 255)

    
print ("done")
img.show()
```

---

```py
# BIGGER BOX SIZE
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


h = 500
w = 500
img = Image.new("RGB", (h,w), (255, 0, 0)) # create a new 15x15 image
pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map
print ("1")

box_size = 25
for i in range (0, h, box_size):
    for j in range(0, w, box_size):
        y, x = i // box_size, j // box_size
        if (y&1)^(x&1):
            for di in range(box_size):
                for dj in range(box_size):
                    pixels[i+di,j+dj] = (0, 0, 0)
        else:
            for di in range(box_size):
                for dj in range(box_size):
                    pixels[i+di,j+dj] = (0, 0, 255)
    
print ("done")
img.show()
```

This will get you the checker pattern for an array.

Comment: So I'm not sure what the shape of your image is, I'm assuming it's just 2D.  And each pixel value is a tuple.  In which case you can just update im[i][j] with a new tuple.  I'll edit my code to match this.

Comment: I can see the checker pattern but its too samll, not how I want it (5x5) > h/5, and w/5

Comment: its 2D, h=500, w=500, background White lets say,. and I want to draw a 5x5 checker pattern on top

Comment: Sounds good.  I updated it to match your code.  One thing to note is that with 500 by 500 pixels, it will look like a mix of the two colors.

Comment: So now I see the pattern but its too small, how do I make it so I can change it to like 5x5.

Comment: Note, this is kind of ad-hoc here.  If h or w is not evenly divisible by box-size you will get an error.

Comment: yes I see that. Logan you are the best man. But I do need the h and w flexibility. So basically what I am trying to get to here is a canvas size of H and W that a user defines. User also gets to decide how many boxes will be displayed > 2x2, 5x5, 20x20.

Comment: Hmm... with flexibility comes edge cases that will need to be handled.  I think the simplest option would be after the user selects box size, height, and width, then adjust the height and width so that they are a multiple of box size.  i.e. if they put in 500, 490 and 25, just round the width up to 500 so that it is evenly divisible by 25.

Answer (score 1):

I had the feeling, that accessing single pixels in Pillow using all those nested loops  isn't the best idea performance-wise.

So, my idea would be to set up a small `(m, n)` checker using (nested) lists, build a Pillow `Image` object from that using [`putdata`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putdata), and simply [`resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) it to the desired size using the [`Image.NEAREST`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#PIL.Image.NEAREST) resampling filter. I added some flexibility for choosing colors and image modes.

```py
from itertools import chain
from math import ceil
from PIL import Image

m, n = (5, 5)                                   # Checker dimension (x, y)
w, h = (100, 100)                               # Final image width and height

c1 = 0      # (224, 64, 64)                     # First color
c2 = 255    # (128, 128, 128)                   # Second color
mode = 'L' if isinstance(c1, int) else 'RGB'    # Mode from first color

# Generate pixel-wise checker, even x dimension
if m % 2 == 0:
    pixels = [[c1, c2] for i in range(int(m/2))] + \
             [[c2, c1] for i in range(int(m/2))]
    pixels = [list(chain(*pixels)) for i in range(ceil(n/2))]

# Generate pixel-wise checker, odd x dimension
else:
    pixels = [[c1, c2] for i in range(ceil(m*n/2))]

# Generate final Pillow-compatible pixel values
pixels = list(chain(*pixels))[:(m*n)]

# Generate Pillow image from pixel values, resize to final image size, and save
checker = Image.new(mode, (m, n))
checker.putdata(pixels)
checker = checker.resize((w, h), Image.NEAREST)
checker.save('checker.png')
```

For the shown configuration, the output would be:

[image: Checker #1]

Switching to RGB, and altering `m`, `w`, and `h`, we might get something like this:

[image: Checker #2]

As already pointed out in the other answers, if `w` or `h` are not whole integer factors of `m` or `n`, then you'll get somehow distorted output (`m = n = 5`, `w = h = 102`):

[image: Checker #3]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Pillow:        8.1.2
----------------------------------------
```